# Приложение выключается через 60 секунд

Tags: android, kotlin

Я только начал изучение и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Кто в силах помочь - буду благодарен.

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.navigation.NavArgs

sealed class Screen (val route : String) {
    object MainScreen : Screen("main_screen")
    object DetailScreen : Screen("detail_screen ")

    fun withArgs (vararg  args: String) : String {
        return  buildString {
            append(route)
            args.forEach { arg ->
                append("/$arg")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
@Composable

fun Navigation () {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController , startDestination = Screen.MainScreen.route) {
        composable(route = Screen.MainScreen.route) {
            MainActivity(navController = navController)

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen.MainScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center ,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp)) {
        Button(onClick = {
                         navController.navigate(Screen.DetailScreen.route)
        }, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End)) {
            Text(text = "fsdfsdf")

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen.DetailScreen () {
    Box (contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Green)){
        Text(text = "Hello")

    }
}




class MainActivity(navController: NavHostController) : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Navigation()



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понятно о чем вы. Разверните вопрос. "выключается" - это как?